# Converting WGS84 UTM to WGS84 ESPG:2039 in CSV file format

Tags: coordinate-system, csv, utm

Is there a simple  free app or a site that you can just load a CSV file with coordinates in UTM and get a CSV file with coordinates in ESPG:2039?

Comment: What about QGIS or R?...

Comment: or `ogr2ogr` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is [gdal](https://gdal.org/index.html). If your input in example is

```
id,easting,northing
1,325000,4256000
2,328000,4150000
```

you can run

```
ogr2ogr -f "CSV" output.csv input.csv \
-s_srs EPSG:32633 \
-t_srs EPSG:2039 \
-oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=easting -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=northing \
-lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY
```

to get

| X | Y | id | easting | northing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1729972.42067606 | 1611951.83316044 | 1 | 325000 | 4256000 |
| -1751639.79879327 | 1502983.34025603 | 2 | 328000 | 4150000 |

Some notes:

- `-s_srs EPSG:32633` to set the source EPSG
- `-t_srs EPSG:2039` to set the target EPSG
- `-oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=easting -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=northing` to set coordinates fields input
- `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY` to set to have the output coordinates